# Cluster SE robust not working when trying to use factor() for multiple binary variables

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to run `clusterSE` for variable zipcode, on a full model that contains "issue types" occurring in each zipcode:

```
fullmod <- glm(countvariable ~ factor(noissue)+factor(landrural)+factor(unpaidwage)+factor(homeprop)+factor(fraudscam)+factor(env)+factor(pensionwelf)+factor(taxi)+factor(med)+factor(edu)+factor(veteran), family=poisson)

SErobust <-cluster.im.glm(fullmod, df, ~ zipcode, ci.level = 0.95, report = TRUE, drop = FALSE, truncate = FALSE, return.vcv = FALSE)
```

Which returns the error:

> Error: cluster-specific model returned error (try drop = TRUE)
> 2.
> stop("cluster-specific model returned error (try drop = TRUE)", call. = FALSE)
> 1.
> cluster.im.glm(fullmod, df, ~zipcode, ci.level = 0.95, report = TRUE, drop = FALSE, truncate = FALSE, return.vcv = FALSE)

"issue type" variables are all ordinary binary variables (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0) with no missing values.

The cluster SE works with my other variables, but everytime I try to put the issue type vars in it returns this error. Any help would be appreciated!!

Updates:

Sample data: it should be noted there is overlap btween the issue vars; for each row there may be **more than one** issue `var==1`. Maybe this is causing the problem??

```
landrural: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
unpaidwage: 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
homeprop: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
fraudscam: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
env: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
pensionwelf: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
taxi: 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
med: 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
edu: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
veteran: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
zipcode: 610000 410000 430000 140000 610000 610000 410000 450000 610000
440000 620000 340000 620000 370000 350000 610000 500000 370000
210000 370000 130000 350000 440000 620000 440000 130000 370000
320000 410000 320000 130000 640000
```

summary(fullmod) results:

```
Call:
glm(formula = countvariable ~  
    factor(landrural) + factor(unpaidwage) + 
    factor(homeprop) + factor(fraudscam) + factor(env) + factor(pensionwelf) + factor(taxi) + factor(med) + factor(edu) + factor(veteran), family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.5428  -0.1652  -0.1105  -0.0791  16.2267  

Coefficients:
                                                 Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)                                      -5.47565    0.23299
factor(landrural)1                               -0.29148    0.10414
factor(unpaidwage)1                               0.76167    0.07896
factor(homeprop)1                                -0.64212    0.08873
factor(fraudscam)1                               -0.45023    0.11940
factor(env)1                                      0.80687    0.10280
factor(pensionwelf)1                             -0.02482    0.13248
factor(taxi)1                                    -0.12217    0.15679
factor(med)1                                      0.26046    0.08299
factor(edu)1                                      0.15460    0.09640
factor(veteran)1                                 -2.37469    0.70952
                                                z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                     -23.502  < 2e-16 ***       
factor(landrural)1                               -2.799 0.005130 ** 
factor(unpaidwage)1                               9.646  < 2e-16 ***
factor(homeprop)1                                -7.237 4.59e-13 ***
factor(fraudscam)1                               -3.771 0.000163 ***
factor(env)1                                      7.849 4.20e-15 ***
factor(pensionwelf)1                             -0.187 0.851376    
factor(taxi)1                                    -0.779 0.435881    
factor(med)1                                      3.138 0.001699 ** 
factor(edu)1                                      1.604 0.108761    
factor(veteran)1                                 -3.347 0.000817 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 13306  on 134847  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 12197  on 134830  degrees of freedom
AIC: 14184

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

Comment: should be noted that i also have other binary/categorical variables, so i do not think it is a problem of binary variables (?)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: And also, what does `summary(fullmod)` say?

Comment: @coffeinjunky yes, I'll make an edit in my og post and include the summary results!